# How to return a redirect to a named route with a variable in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, variables, frameworks

so this is what I tried (doesn´t work). I am happy with any advice :)

Controller:

```
public function show($id){
        $URL = route('post', ['id' => $id]);
        
        return redirect($URL);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', [postController::class, 'show'])->name('post');
```

Comment: This is the error mssg: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: [generating-urls-to-named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)
To redirect to a named route we use: `return redirect()->route('post', ['id' => $id]);`

```php
public function show($id){
   return redirect()->route('post', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

However, This implementation will throw an error. It's a loop. The route (in web.php) calls `show()` in the controller. And, the controller redirects back to the same controller. it doesn't make any sense.